# Subsites under same application pool

Tags: iis-7, application-pool

I got a website, will create many subsites under this one ( may be around 300). Can I place all these susbites under one application pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host several web sites in the same application pool, but you should understand that you're creating a dependency among the sites in the same application pool -- they'll run as part of the same process, and if you have to restart the application pool for any reason, it will affect all sites in that pool.  In some cases, this might make sense for you, but you should probably review online documentation to be sure this is what you want to do.

[Introduction to IIS 7 Architecture](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/101/introduction-to-iis-architecture/)

[Managing Application Pools in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449%28WS.10%29.aspx)